# iOS: How to show alertview while app in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, iphone-privateapi

I want to show an Alert when the app is in background. I have found the following question and my intention is almost same. But with no working code sample

[Show an alert when iOS app is in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36669772/show-an-alert-when-ios-app-is-in-the-background)

I know, it's NOT possible with any public api. But i am also NOT going to submit to app store. So any code sample will be appreciated.

Comment: "it's now possible with any public api" not sure at all about this

Comment: @AnthoninC. ,  Sorry. typing mistake. Edited.

Comment: Your link _does_ answer the question, and you aren't asking anything different here.

Comment: @matt,  yes you are right. I am not asking anything different here.  But also that link doesn't have any working solution. I have tried them all.